# Partitioning a set of integers (with Alice and Bob)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, inequality, integers, set-partition

Let $ d_1,\ldots,d_n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 2} $ (not necessarily distinct) be given. Define $ D:=\operatorname{lcm}(d_1,\ldots,d_n) $ and $ d:=\sum_{i=1}^n d_i $.

(1) Alice claims that whenever $ \lbrace d/D\rbrace \ge \frac{1}{2} $ holds (where $ \lbrace x \rbrace $ denotes the fractional part of $ x $), she is able to find a partition of $ \lbrace T_j \rbrace_{j=1}^{\left\lfloor d/D\right\rfloor} $ of $ \lbrace 1,\ldots,n \rbrace $ such that $ \sum_{m \in T_j} d_m \ge D $ ($j=1,\ldots, \left\lfloor d/D \right\rfloor $) are satisfied.

(2) Bob claims that whenever $ \lbrace d/D\rbrace \le \frac{1}{2} $ holds (where $ \lbrace x \rbrace $ denotes the fractional part of $ x $), he is able to find a partition of $ \lbrace T_j \rbrace_{j=1}^{\left\lceil d/D \right\rceil} $ of $ \lbrace 1,\ldots,n \rbrace $ such that $ \sum_{m \in T_j} d_m \le D $ ($j=1,\ldots, \left\lceil d/D \right\rceil $) are satisfied.

Are both of them right?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you worked out an example for small $n$ (say $n = 3$)?

Comment: I cannot say, whether these statements are true. But from all I ever generated randomly, Alice and Bob were right. So I guess, both claims See correct, but I have no idea how to construct the partition.

Comment: It seems to be hard to find counterexamples to Alice's claim. One of them is given by $d_1=21$, $d_2=14$ (twice), $d_3=6$ (six times) where such a partition does not exist. But here we are far away from $\lbrace d/D \rbrace \ge 1/2$.